# In Express/EJS, how do I change the default layout?

Tags: layout, node.js, express, ejs

I don't want it to be layout.ejs.

I want to set my layout to be another template for THIS specific controller.

Comment: Hey! Please consider choosing an accepted answer to this old question.

Answer (score 18):

Try using:

```
app.set("view options", { layout: "mylayout.jade" });
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the `layout` option to `res.render()`

```
res.render('page', { layout: 'mylayout.jade' })
```

Comment: but I want to use ANOTHER layout.

Comment: OK, I think this is it :
`res.render('page', { layout: 'mylayout.jade' });`

Answer (score 5):

### Set custom default layout

Just set layout property in express app settings.

```
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout');
```

### Set custom layout for single render

Just pass layout as render locals object.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('the-view', { layout: 'specific-layout' });
);
```

More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts

Answer (score 4):

Providing you're using the [Ejs-express-layouts module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-ejs-layouts) you can specify a layout for a particular view, overriding the default:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('aView', { layout: 'someSpecificLayout' })
})
```